# UML2 Activity Diagram: Object Flow and Control Flow

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I would like to model the following activity by means of a UML2 activity diagram:

1. Execute Action1. This action produces two output parameters: Object1
   and Object2.
2. Execute Action2. This action requires Object2 as an input parameter. It DOES NOT REQUIRE Object1 as an input parameter.
3. Execute Action3. This action requires both Object1 and Object2 (output parameters of Action1) as input parameters.

See the following diagram (just ignore the name "LoopNode1"):

[image: UML2 Activity Diagram]

I think I haven't fully understood the concepts of tokens, object flow and control flow in UML2. How can I make clear that Action2 is PERFORMED BEFORE Action3? IMHO, in diagram shown, the order of actions performed is not clear, is it? I want to realise the activity exactly as described above, without any parallelism!

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `synchronization bar (join)` to indicate dependency (see [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_activitydiagram.html)). Alternatively, you can use sequence diagram instead of activity diagram - order is defined naturally there.

Comment: with a synchronization bar / join, the object flow is lost. So your answer means the only way to express _both_ object flow _and_ order is by using Sequence Diagram?

Answer (score 0):

As UML 2.5.1 states ...

> Object nodes hold data that is input to and output from executable nodes, and moves across object flow edges. Control nodes specify sequencing of executable nodes via control flow edges

... I would argue that it is clear that your Action2 is executed before Action3, since the branch containing Action2 is the only one that specifies any sequencing / ControlFlow (ActivityEdge) elements.

To be honest I'm not quite sure how to interpret the following sentence and if it has some implications to my arguing:

> Activities are essentially what are commonly called “control anddata flow” models. Such models of computation are inherently concurrent, as any sequencing of activity node executionis modeled explicitly by activity edges, and no ordering is mandated for any computation not explicitly sequenced.